# Manga about people controlling elements

Tags: story-identification, manga

The release of the live-action adaptation of *Avatar: The Last Airbender* reminded me of a manga I heard about when I was a teenager.

I have only limited information since I read about it in France in the 90s in a video games magazine that had a section about mangas. Knowing this, I guess the manga was originally published in Japan in the 90s or the 80s, then translated to French in the 90s.

The manga was about people (maybe whole families or clans) who could control elements: fire, water (or ice?), air, or earth. In addition to the 4 elements, there was a fifth one, called Ether, that was known to be stronger than the other one. In the current timeline, the person controlling Ether was missing (disappeared? hidden? death?), and this started or worsened the conflicts and tensions before the other characters. I remember quite well a panel shown in the article where a character was saying that

> It is because Ether, who is above us, didn't show up, that things are such a mess.

The style was a simple and "clean" style like Dragon Ball. It looked interesting but never had the chance to buy it in my small town. **Any idea on the title?**

Comment: https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Toaru_Majutsu_no_Index_Wiki?

Comment: Presumably there were not very many officially published manga in the 90s. Is it possible to find it by checking official publishers, or French-language aggregators that mention publishers? Glénat has records going back to the 90s on their website, for example: https://www.glenat.com/manga/catalogue

Comment: @Valorum: that one is too recent. And it seems to be about "people with powers", not just controlling elements. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @qazmlpok: France has had a liking for mangas since the 80s, 90s, but the list should not be too long. I checked lists like "tops of mangas from the 90s", or bookstores (FNAC, etc) but didn't think about checking the editor's websites. Good idea